# Procedure to delete table rows

Tags: oracle, perl, delete-row

I am testing this perl script which basically call procedure and run DELETE on 2 tables.

Questions:

1. Is there any issue with the procedure or calling procedure in perl?
2. Can I use 2 deletes in single procedure?

   > ```
   > Procedure delete (v_db_id in number)
   >
   > IS BEGIN
   >
   > DELETE from TAB1
   > where db_id = v_db_id;
   >
   > DELETE from TAB2
   > where db_id = v_db_id;
   >
   > END delete;
   > ```

PERL Script:

```
sub getdelete {

my $dbID = shift
my $rs;
my $SQL;

$SQL = q{delete (?)};

$rs = executeQuery($SQL,$dbID);
$rs -> fetchrow();
$rs -> finish();
}
```

PERL Script calling subroutine getdelete as below:

```
&getdelete ($dbID);
```

Error:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD Error: OCIStmtExecute)[for statement "delete"]
```

Comment: You should be using [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) like the rest of us.

Comment: thanks mob for your comments.. actually script is using DBD everywhere so can't really use DBI.

Comment: giving `delete` as a name to procedure isn't very good idea, and you shouldn't `select myprocedure() from dual` as procedure can't return anything (function does that).

Comment: @mpapec   updated procedure select and removed dbID from executeQuery() ... still errors out which I updated in actual posting.

Comment: how does `executeQuery` look like? how do you connect to oracle and where is db handle stored?

Comment: @mpapec  I have updated execute query.. passing in value for procedure.. currently it does gets dbID value in procedure but still fails to execute query. executeQuery gets sql and variable value to run query.

Comment: huh? DBD are never used directly. They're they drivers used by DBI.

Comment: @Khallas301 solution would be trivial if you find out where DBI handle is stored, and it seems that `executeQuery` knows where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DELETE` doesn't takes an expression that results in a table id; it takes a table id literal. As such, you can't use replaceable parameters. You need to construct the table id literal, which `$dbh->quote_identifier` can do.

```
my $sql = 'DELETE '.$dbh->quote_identifier($dbID);
$dbh->do($sql);
```

You are using a module that wraps DBI in a very poor way<sup>1</sup>. I have no way of knowing if it'll give access to the database handle or to the handle's `quote_identifier` method, but at least now you know what to look for.

---

Notes:

1. There are three ways to wrap DBI that make sense:

   1. To add functions or override some minor aspect of existing functions.

      For example, DBI database statements don't have the selectrow_* methods founds on database handles. Adding these without restricting access to the rest of DBI is perfectly fine.
   2. To provide a higher level abstraction of a database, such as an ORM like [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass). These are massive systems with thousands if not tens of thousands of lines.

      If your wrapper provide a new database interface and its code fits on two screens, it's doing something wrong.
   3. To centralise all DB code by providing application-specific functions like `create_user`, `fetch_daily_report_data`, etc. SQL isn't passed

      If your wrapper attempts to this but provides functions that expect SQL, it's doing something wrong.

   What doesn't make sense is to attempt to simplify DBI, and this appears to be what your wrapper does. DBI actually provides a very simple interface. Any attempts to simplify it is bound to leave out something critical.